# NeDB query with projection syntax error

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, nedb, feathersjs

I get a syntax on a simple NeDB request. What is wrong with my query written for Feathers/NeDB?

```
var workFilter = {
         query: {
                _id: { $nin: workIds}
         },
         { customerId: 1, productId: 1, _id: 1}
}
```

Thank you

Comment: Basically, your `JSON` is invalid. Doesn't maintain a `key value` for the `projection` part of the filter.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
datastore
.find({_id:{$nin:workIds}})
.projection({customerId:1, productId:1})
.exec(callback);
```

The `_id` property will always be included.